# Ansible hosts configuration using private key and sudo user

Tags: sudo, ssh-keys, ansible

Hi I have written a playbook for Ansible to install a few application. I am having trouble as I have to run every thing as root which is not a good idea.

So I have created a sudo user and have created a private key for authentication.

Could some one help me in defining the hosts file for this scenario.

My current hosts file is like this:

```
[webserver]
web-01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.11 ansible_ssh_user=root
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your new hosts file will be look like this:

```
[webserver]
web-01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.11 ansible_ssh_user=USERNAME ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/secure/mykey
```

But please also make **sudo: True** in your playbook like this:

```
  ---
   - hosts: webserver
     sudo: True 
     remote_user: USERNAME
     gather_facts: True
     # Run these tasks  
     tasks:
       - name: Run this task.....
```

**One Important thing** that your sudo user should be password less, to achieve that you should edit your sudoer file.
If you are using the CentOS, then please edit the /etc/sudoers file and add the following line

```
USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

please add this line after the last line which says

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

If you are using the Ubuntu, then use the **visudo** command, find and edit the below line:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Great, can you please tell me that which section help you. Thanks

Comment: I used this 
`#Running as root user
web-01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.11 ansible_ssh_user=root

#Running as sudo user
web-02 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.0.103 ansible_ssh_user=user_name ansible_sudo_pass='password'`